# Consuming Tableau Web Data Connector from ETL Tool or Python

Tags: etl, tableau-api, pentaho

Is it possible to get data from a Tableau Web Data Connector using Python or an ETL tool like Pentaho instead of using Tableau / Tableau Prep?

Comment: using Pentaho, answer is no, however you can try http client, rest client  pentaho step to check if that works

Comment: if you're using Python, skip the WDC altogether and go straight to the source.